# change SSIS package protection level before deployment

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I'm developing SSIS project locally using project deployment model. I use SQL Server Authentication to connect to remote server. During this period *Protection level* is set to *EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey*.

However, upon deployment this package will be executed in a completely different environment, using SSPI security context and with environment variables from SSIS catalog.

This means that right now, before deployment I have to manually change *Protection level* to *DontSaveSensitive* inside a project and every package in it. Only after that tedious procedure I deploy the project to remote server.

I cannot keep *DontSaveSensitive* locally because every time I run a package it will ask me for a password. I cannot deploy with *EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey* either, because it gives error saying it cannot decrypt some of the values (passwords).

My question is how can skip changes of protection level manually every time I deploy a package? How can I automate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're in project deployment mode, which means you are deploying to the SSISDB, there's no need for what you're doing ;)

When you deploy, the isdeploymentwizard.exe is handling all that for your

[image]

As part of the deployment, the "Changing protection level" step switches the packages to [ServerStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx#Anchor_3) level

Comment: thank you! it didn't occur to me that this is a just a warning message, not an error that I have to do something about